# Anylogic : How to work with resource pool optimization?

Tags: optimization, simulation, anylogic

first of all, I am new in Anylogic and no idea to know about this case. If you don't mind please tell me resource for complete optimization material resource.

[image: process picture]

I have operation process above, and want to know how many minimize person for each shift I and II for process I and Process II. should I have variabel for resource pool? and how to link it to optimization objective?

Please help me and tell step by step. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File->New->Experiment` and select Optimization from the list. There on the right side, you need to define your objective function and constraints. This topic is explained [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/optimization.html) in AnyLogic documentation. You should have a parameter for each of the resources. In the optimization objective you need to say minimize `noResourcePoolProcess1` for example. And a good constraint would be utilization being below 85% for example. Otherwise minimization will not care if your system is throttled.

[image]